# Is there any speech to IPA software?

Tags: ipa, speech-recognition

Does anyone know of a software that does speech to IPA transcription? It seems like this is an easier problem than speech to text but searching for it online didn't give me any results.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to [this question](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/computationally-differentiating-between-cvc-vcv-and-cv-syllables/4054#4054)

Comment: I'm asking for something that works directly from speech. The examples in the linked question are all text based.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment and added a different link, which will hopefully be what you need (see links in the last paragraph of the answer)

Comment: Also see [this question](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/convert-audio-recording-of-word-to-ipa-representation) and its accompanying comments and responses.

Comment: The indicated duplicate is indeed a duplicate, but none of the three "answers" are actually answers.  They all just discuss whether creating such software is easy or difficult.